# listenglobal renderer event trigger in angular 6 testing script

Tags: testing, angular6, renderer

I want to test my RolesComponent listenGlobal Renderer method. RolesComponent code below.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AhanaService } from '../../services/ahana.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-roles',
    template: '<div><button roleId="1">test click</button></div>',
    styleUrls: ['./roles.component.css']
})
export class RolesComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(public router: Router, private ahanaService: AhanaService, private renderer: Renderer) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.hasAttribute("roleId")) {
                var roleId = event.target.getAttribute('roleId')
                // console.log('/configuration/update-role/' + roleId)
                this.router.navigate(['/configuration/update-role/' + roleId]);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

how to convert RolesComponent.spec.ts and `ngAfterViewInit(): void {        this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event) => {` method call.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test that your click listener is behaving as expected, then you can manually call the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook from your test and assert that `router.navigate()` is called as expected. In order to do this, you can mock and spy on the `router.navigate` method and expect it to have been called with a particular url route. The result is very similar to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774936/9671333).

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RolesComponent } from './roles.component';

describe('RolesComponent', () => {
  let component: RolesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RolesComponent>;
  const routerSpy = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate') }; // Create our router mock, which we will spy on

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ RolesComponent ],
      providers: [{ provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy }], // Register our mock router as a provider
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RolesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should register click listener', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngAfterViewInit(); // Call the lifecycle hook
    const button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
    button.click(); // "Click" the button
    tick();
    expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/configuration/update-role/1']); // Assert that our mock was called
  }));
});
```

Comment: Where is the `listenGlobal` method call.?

Comment: There is a `router.navigate` call in the callback that you pass to `listenGlobal`. Without more context, that appears to be the functionality that you would want to test here, because that is what kicks the user to the update role page.